# Unable to Inherit from MediaElement Class

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mediaelement

I am trying to create a custom MediaElement , and the 1st thing I need is to inherit it from the MediaElement .

But this is simply not happneing when I try to inherit like following:

```
CustomMediaControl : MediaElement
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MediaElement` is declared a `sealed` class -- cannot be inherited.

Documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Do you happen to know why they chose to do that for Silverlight?  I don't know why I expected an MSDN article to tell me.

Comment: @Erode This is a wild, wild guess, and more likely wrong than right, but it may have to do with DRM. I imagine that if you could subclass `MediaElement` you could somehow circumvent it. Again, I don't even know if that makes sense, but it is a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve this might not be suitable, but if you're using Silverlight have a look at the Silverlight Media Framework http://smf.codeplex.com/.

It comes with a whole heap of features and it has it's own mediaelement, which you might be able to use as your base.

Good luck,
Ola